# Copy-paste code vs fork + exec for external program

Tags: linux, subprocess, shared-libraries

I need some programs that don't have shared libraries. Should I dissect the program and include the code inside my program and have proper error handling but have to update manually and be open to bugs, or should i fork and call the program directly and have no error handling and be dependent on the program syntax, but have it update with the system?

Comment: If shared libraries are out of the question, have you considered putting the common code in a static library instead?

Comment: I've included all the modified code inside my program. Calling external programs was bound to fail.